# replacing a dynamic string with 'comma' - Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface

I am trying to write a windows Batch file to obtain below OUTPUT for given INPUT

**INPUT:**

```
//Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/abcd/mnop/HealthCheck.java - edit change 1111111
 //Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/abcd/mnop/HealthStatus.java - edit change 1111111
 //Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/xyz/Relations.java - edit change 1111111
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
target/classes/test/abcd/mnop/, target/classes/test/abcd/mnop/, target/classes/test/xyz
```

Below is the script I used, however replacing filename is not working.

```
@echo off
set "File2Read=files_list.tmp"
SET "BINARY_PATH="
set "FILENAME="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BINARY_FILENAME="
set "lastPart="
set "replaceBinaryPath=target/classes/"
SET "replaceBinaryFileName=,"
set "basePath=//ATT/Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
set "line=%%a"
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims= " %%a in ("!line!") do  set FILENAME=%%a

set "BINARY_FILENAME=!FILENAME:%basePath%=%replaceBinaryPath%!"
if not !FILENAME!==!BINARY_FILENAME! (
for %%a in ("!BINARY_FILENAME!/.") do set "lastPart=%%~nxa"
set "BINARY_PATH=!BINARY_FILENAME:!lastPart!=%replaceBinaryFileName%!"
echo !BINARY_PATH!
)
)
endLocal
```

here, everything works as expected, except below statement,

```
set "BINARY_PATH=!BINARY_FILENAME:!lastPart!=%replaceBinaryFileName%!"
```

Since ‘`lastPart`’ will be the dynamically changing-value, in order to replace it with ‘comma’ It was supposed to work with `!lastPart!` but its not working and output is word `‘lastPart’`
We cant use `%lastPart%` as it is dynamic variable.

Please help me with replacing a dynamic string with 'comma'.

Please help me out here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `%%~nxa` expression directly, I only changed the parameter name to `%%C`

```
..
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
  set "line=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims= " %%a in ("!line!") do  set FILENAME=%%a

  set "BINARY_FILENAME=!FILENAME:%basePath%=%replaceBinaryPath%!"
  if not !FILENAME!==!BINARY_FILENAME! (
    for %%C in ("!BINARY_FILENAME!/.") do (
      set "BINARY_PATH=!BINARY_FILENAME:%%~nxC=%replaceBinaryFileName%!"
      echo !BINARY_PATH!
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jeb's version didn't work for me, here an alternative

- as the usage of `%%~dpa` changes the the non windows path separator `/` to `\` it is corrected.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\09\24\SO_52482593.cmd
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "File2Read=files_list.tmp"
set "BINARY_PATH="
set "replaceBinaryPath=target/classes/"
set "replaceBinaryFileName=, "
set "Output="
for /f %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
  for /f "tokens=5* delims=\/" %%b in ("%%~dpa") do (
    Set "Output=!Output!%replaceBinaryFileName%%replaceBinaryPath%%%c"
  )
)
Set "Output=%Output:\=/%"
Echo %Output:~2%
endLocal
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\09\24\SO_52482593.cmd
target/classes/test/abcd/mnop/, target/classes/test/abcd/mnop/, target/classes/test/xyz/
```